What would be the legal situation had Xander Elliards been arrested under the Section 20 of the Police and Fire Reform Act
It is in the news that Xander Elliards, a journalist reporting on a protest was threatened with arrest.  There is a video of the encounter on twitterX.  As I see it the relevant facts are:

The encounter took place on a road "said to be around 100m from the protest site", with no one but police visible (Xander Elliards is recording the video I assume)
The police officer acknowledges that Xander Elliards is a journalist
The police officer instructs the journalist to leave, and threatens him with arrest if he does not do so.
At this point the journalist moves to the side of the road, presumably so as to not physically obstruct anything
After this, the police officer says: "you're still gonna not take a direction from a constable in uniform? Under section 20 of the Police and Fire Reform Act I'm carrying out my duty as a constable you're now being obstructive to the police, you may be arrested [video ends]"
A spokesperson for Police Scotland said in a statement: "During the protest an officer engaged with a journalist and asked him to move away from an area where officers were taking part in an operational briefing.

I have not found an easy summary of this power, but Police Scotland / College of Policing (?) say this of the use of this power:

Section 20 of the Police and Fire Reform (Scotland) Act 2012 details the duty of a
constable and provides Police Scotland with authority to act in accordance with the
law, which is required under certain elements of ECHR.
This act can be used throughout Scotland to provide officers with some confidence
around directing and containing groups who the Police may wish to gain some control
over. It can also assist with keeping people away from groups or an area which the
police wish to retain an element of control over.
Officers can be briefed to ensure a lawful and corporate message can be relayed to
the public such as:-
‘‘It is reasonably suspected that there may be acts of disorder in this area and
there may be danger to life or damage to property. It is the duty of the Police to
maintain order and to protect life and property and I therefore require you to…”
This may assist officers either inadvertently relaying an unclear or compromising
statement to the public which could result in confusion or complaint.

If we take this at face value, the police are being honest about the reason for the encounter, and in the hypothetical that the officer arrested Xander Elliards what would be the legal situation?  Could a journalist being in "an area where officers were taking part in an operational briefing" be reasonably interpreted as "being obstructive to the police" under the Police and Fire Reform Act?  If an arrest was made in a situation where it was not reasonable to believe the Police and Fire Reform Act allowed arrest what would be the legal situation?  Does it matter that these powers concern the ECHR?

Why the close votes?  It isn't opinion based.  This can be answered based on what the law says about recording police activity in a public place.

I don't the UK law well, but in the US police can only arrest a person when there is a clear and reasonable belief that a law is or has been broken. What law do you break by watching or reporting on civil unrest? Seems like a clear case of wrongful arrest.

@NeilMeyer in the UK and many other places police have the power to issue a “move along” order. Refusing to follow that order is an offence and grounds for arrest
